# ネットワークACLで特定のサービスのみアクセス許可し、それ以外を拒否したい。

Tags: aws, network

ネットワークACLとセキュリティグループを用いて特定のインターネットサービスのみの通信を許可したいです。
通信制御させたいのはプライベートvpcに閉じこめてるworkspaces(windowsのリモートデスクトップ)から特定サービス(ここではgoogle)を想定しています。

### 試したこと

#### パターン1

例としてgoogleのインターネットサービスのみ通信許可しそれ以外を拒否したい場合として
ネットワークACLを以下のように設定しました。

```
インバウンド
ルール1: プロトコル:すべてのTCP :ソースIP: 172.217.31.132/32 許可
ルール2: プロトコル:すべてのTCP :ソースIP: 0.0.0.0/0  拒否

アウトバウンド
ルール1: プロトコル:すべてのTCP :ソースIP: 0.0.0.0/0  許可
```

上のように設定してもインターネット通信が遮断され、期待したネットワーク制御が出来ませんでした。

#### パターン2

ACLではアクセスをすべて許可しセキュリティグループで特定サービスのみ許可することを試みました。

ACL設定：

```
インバウンド
ルール1: プロトコル:すべてのTCP :ソースIP: 0.0.0.0/0  許可

アウトバウンド
ルール1: プロトコル:すべてのTCP :ソースIP: 0.0.0.0/0  許可
```

セキュリティグループ設定：

```
インバウンド
プロトコル:すべてのTCP :ソースIP: 172.217.31.132/32 許可

アウトバウンド
ルール1: プロトコル:すべてのTCP :ソースIP: 0.0.0.0/0  許可
```

しかしこのように設定しても、インターネット通信が全て通信できるようになってしまいました。
どうすれば特定サービスのみの通信を許可してそれ以外を拒否できるでしょうか？

Comment: そもそもネットワークACLにもセキュリティグループにもinboundとoutboundの設定があります。しかし質問文にはどちらを設定したのか、そして反対側はどう設定したのか言及されていません。

Comment: >>sayuri追記しました

Comment: 「特定のインターネットサービスのみの通信を許可」、「インターネット通信が遮断され」、「インターネット通信が全て通信できる」はそれぞれどこからどこへの通信を想定されているのでしょうか？ 特にVPC内からVPC外へ向けての通信なのか、それともVPC外からVPC内へ向けての通信なのか、肝心の通信方向について言及がありません。

Comment: vpc内からvpc外へ向けての通信になります

Comment: 必要に応じて AWS のサポートに直接問い合わせることも検討してください。 https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/tech-support-guidelines/